# bing map APi angularjs 1.6.4 Error

Tags: jquery, angularjs, callback, bing-api

I am scratching my head trying to figure out integrating bing map api to angularjs 1.6.4 . Can any one help..?.

Here is my html

https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMapScenario' async defer>

below code is inside Body tag.

my angular controller code is as follows

$scope.map = null;

```
    function loadMapScenario() {

        console.log('Load scenario called');

        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), {
            credentials: 'Ao-Rs8NHwtlEI5piXQCcxMZrTfAt9zbg7a-8hB4PLAcc0eo5nZPN84aY16noJGKS',
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(41.264675, -96.041927),
            zoom: 4
        });
    }

    //$scope.map = null;
    $scope.init = function () {


        console.log('Map init');
        $scope.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), {
            credentials: 'api Key',
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(41.264675, -96.041927),
            zoom: 4
        });
    };

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.init();
    });
```

Issues:

I get following error

Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined

and

Uncaught TypeError: window[Microsoft.Maps.CallbackOnLoad] is not a function

Any idea what wrong in this code ?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined` you're not loading the Bing Map API before running your code.

Looking at the [Bing API](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#invokeEventHandler+HTML) docs it seems like you need to define a callback function on the `window` object which will be called when the script loads.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I rechecked my work. I was loading this again inside my controller using the loadMapScenario function. The GitHub sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsV8CodeSamples/blob/master/Samples/Experimental/Map_WithAngular1.html) also loads the map inside the controller. The callback does not appear to work with Angular 1 at this time. However, you should be able to load with the call. I do think it helps to put the mapcontrol tag after your script file. See the Github example, which does work.

EDIT 2: I managed to hack something together that is DECIDEDLY NOT Angular best practices compliant. In my script tag I define the callback function mapLoaded. Outside and before controller definitions, I define the following:

```
 var mapReady = false;

    function mapLoaded() {
       mapReady = true;
    }
```

And then in the controller, I have a simple monitor function that waits for the variable to be true or the a specified amount of time to elapse. It's ugly, but to address the other answer to this topic, I've seen lots of people say that you can add this function to the window object, but no code that works, and I've tried it every which way there is a sample.

Removing previous bad code in answer strikeout below to shorten post and keep it relevant without losing the wrong answer completely.

<strike>It looks like your bing script tag is wrong somehow -- That's what would produce the 'Microsoft is not defined' eror. Also, if you have the callback function defined in the script tag, you don't need it in the $scope.init, and you don't need the document ready.</strike>

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=AsyncMapLoad" async defer></script>
```

I changed the callback name, but that is a direct copy and paste from some working angular code to load maps and the autosuggest feature.

The relevant part of app.js looks like this (I have extracted some of the map code to a service for my own reasons, so the first function is in a service referenced in the second function which is in a controller that references the service: